# laravel session authentication in middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-middleware

I have stored some value in session and checked in it middleware for authentication .my session timeout is SESSION_LIFETIME=120 .when its page is ideal for 30 minutes and does some action on it middleware validate it's true and go forward but due to code it give some error in function but again I refresh the code it redirect to login page

laravel version 6
handle method

````
    {
        $this->authuser   = getLogedinUser();

  if(Arr::has($this->authuser,['id','name','email',token]) && Arr::get($this->authuser,'token',0))
        {
            return $next($request);
        }
        return redirect('/login');
    }```
````

Comment: what error you got.?

Comment: in function, I get value from the session and process it but this stage session has nothing that why get an error for further code process

Comment: if you logout from application laravel removes all of session

Comment: when I log out its remove all session

Comment: yes it's correct what you want  then

Comment: when the page is ideal and I click on some link it goes to certain function (even middleware is checking for the session) that comes error in function but again I refresh the page it throws to the login page(middleware else condition work here)

Answer (score 0):

**Try This**

```
  public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if(!$this->session->has('lastActivityTime'))
            $this->session->put('lastActivityTime',time());
        elseif(time() - $this->session->get('lastActivityTime') > $this->getTimeOut()){
            $this->session->forget('lastActivityTime');
            Auth::logout();
            return redirect('auth/login')->withErrors(['You had not activity in 30 minutes']);
        }
        $this->session->put('lastActivityTime',time());
        return $next($request);
    }
```